# How to create and insert an Interactive Dynamic SVG in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, jquery-svg

I need to insert **SVG dynamically**, however it should be **INTERACTIVE** ...

**Am I doing the right thing?**

The problem I'm having is that SVG does not appear on the page, and if I use it as `<image>` it does not get INTERACTIVE.

**HTML5 CODE**

```
 <!-- PLANTA -->
    <main class="container-fluid d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100">
       <!-- SVG -->
       <div id="info-box"></div>
       <svg id="....." xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="500">
            <object  data="src/data/shoppings/plants/via-parque/via_parque_P1_20160909.svg" type="image/svg+xml" src="src/data/shoppings/plants/via-parque/via_parque_P1_20160909.png" > </object>
        </svg>
    </main>
```

*JS CODE*

```
    <script>


    // Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "src/data/shoppings/lib/shoppings.json", function(data) {
    var tst  = document.getElementById("plant-src-svg")
    var rect = document.createElementNS(tst,'object');
    rect.setAttribute('type', "image/svg+xml");
    rect.setAttribute('data', "src/data/shoppings/plants/via-parque/via_parque_P1_20160909.svg");
    tst.appendChild(rect);
    console.log(tst)

})
.always(function() {
    console.log( "complete" );
  })
  .done(function() {
    console.log( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log( "error" );
  }); 




        </script>
```

Comment: `<object>` is a HTML element. Do not wrap it in a `<svg>` tag.

Comment: Also the first parameter in the `creatElementNS()` method has to be a valid XML namespace string. For SVG, that has to be `"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`.  The second parameter has to be a valid SVG tag name. As @ccprog has already said, `object` is not a valid SVG element.

Answer (score 0):

The `<object>` shouldn't be inside an `<svg>`.  Just append your object as a child of the parent div.

```
<!-- PLANTA -->
<main id="main" class="container-fluid d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100">
   <div id="info-box"></div>
   <!-- object will be inserted here -->
</main>
```

JS:

```
var main = document.getElementById("main")
var object = document.createElement('object');
object.setAttribute('type', "image/svg+xml");
object.setAttribute("width", "500");
object.setAttribute("height", "500");
object.setAttribute('data', "src/data/shoppings/plants/via-parque/via_parque_P1_20160909.svg");
main.appendChild(object);
```